# Use of BETWEEN function from MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I am an amateur programmer and have recently been facing a challenge.

I am trying to select a data between range of dates but despite numerous attempts have been unsuccessful. Can someone help me with the code of pulling up data between date ranges.

My code is:

```
<?php


$tdate = $_POST['toDate'];
$fdate = $_POST['fromDate'];

    mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass") or die("Couldn't connect!");
    mysql_select_db("db_name") or die("Couldn't find db");

    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db_table BETWEEN saledate '$tdate' AND '$fdate' ");
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($data);

    if (!$result) {
    echo "No result";
    } else {
        echo $result;
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't do Query like that. Use PDO.

Regarding your SQL is wrong. The right is:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db_table WHERE saledate  BETWEEN '$tdate' AND '$fdate' ");
```

Comment: Thanks yes123 that helps, since I am a really new programmer what command shall i use to display the entire data between these two dates on the page.

Comment: I am sorry i was unable to understand as I am not to that stage to understand the link. I am at a very basic level. However, if I am using mysql_num_rows function its showing me 2 and mysql_fetch_array it results array. Kinda confused..

Comment: @Darsh: you should force yourself to use PDO, it's simpler than it may look at first sight

Comment: i haven't started programming with objects in PHP. Shall look more into it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You sql should be this

```
SELECT * FROM db_table WHERE saledate BETWEEN $tdate AND $fdate
```

Comment: Thanks Ash that helps, since I am a really new programmer what command shall i use to display the entire data between these two dates on the page.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, instead of

```
$result = mysql_fetch_array($data);
    if (!$result) {
    echo "No result";
    } else {
        echo $result;
    }
```

write the following code.

```
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($data)) 
{
echo $result['Fieldname1'];
......
......
echo $result['Fieldnamen'];
}
```

In place of fieldname, write the fields from your table. The fields you want to display.

Comment: i hope you know how to style it.